# Выборка из дочерней таблицы по количеству

Tags: sql, mysql

Приветствую.

Есть бд вида:

Родитель:

Новости

```
id text
1  a
2  e
3  p
```

Дочерняя:

Комментарии:

```
id text news_id
1  yo   1
...
```

Мне нужно получить 10 новостей и для каждой из них по три комментария:

Мои варианты:

1) Запрос в цикле - нет

2) Запрос для комментариев типа IN (news_id) но тогда LIMIT будет использоваться для всех комментариев, а мне надо для каждой новости

Подразумевается, что первый запрос вытаскивает 10 новостей, как одним запросом достать по 3 комментария для каждой новости, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень хочется сделать это одним запросом, то вот один довольно очевидный вариант:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `news` 
LEFT JOIN `posts` ON 
`news`.`id`=`posts`.`news_id` 
AND 
`posts`.`id`<=IFNULL((
    SELECT `id` 
    FROM `posts` 
    WHERE `posts`.`news_id`=`news`.`id` 
    ORDER BY  `posts`.`id` 
    LIMIT 2,1
    ), ~0)
WHERE `news`.`id`<=IFNULL((
SELECT `id` FROM `news` 
ORDER BY `id` 
LIMIT 9,1
), ~0);
```

~0 — это максимальное целое. Как видно, коррелированный подзапрос не очень хороший, может быть, его можно переписать.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю что проще, а возможно и быстрее (если не переподключаться к базе каждый раз), будет делать по одному запросу на каждую новость. Т.е. вытащить десять новостей и потом для каждой из них сделать по одному запросу достающему комменты.

Быстрее это может быть за счёт того что оптимизатору проще оптимизировать простые запросы.